# How to export Haxe in HIDE

Tags: ide, haxe

I'm using Haxe on the HAXE IDE, HIDE. I can simply create code for any language, but I don't know how to export it. It didn't have any export options, and no tutorials explain this. How do I export it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HIDE IDE is still under development and lacks features, the current one might not yet support the export functionality you are used to under other IDE's or any functionality at all for that matter.

If you want an IDE with more functionality for haxe, you might want to check out: 
http://haxe.org/documentation/introduction/editors-and-ides.html

Just a small remark though:
"Code for any language"? HIDE is a specific idea for Haxe development on any platform, not for any language. (So you can use it under Linux, Mac OS and windows).

To run your code under that HIDE, you can just press "F5" or go to Project -> Run. If you just want to build it you can also go to Project -> Build. My guess is that that is what you meant by "Export".

(By the way, if you want a tool which has support for many programming languages you can either use notepad++ not much IDE functionality, but more highlighting and some sort of auto-complete at least), or plugins for other IDE's such as eclipse / visual studio.)